# Copying a reduced noise model from an IBM device

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, noise

I need to use the noise model coming from a large IBM device. Nonetheless, I do not need to use the whole Noise Model. I only need the information of let's say qubits [10:15] and [20:25]. That would be, I only need the noise model information of those 10 qubits. Then, I need to use that reduced noise model into my own simulated device that consists of only 10 qubits. So all in all, I need to copy the noise model from IBM device qubits [10:15], [20:25] and use it in my own devices [0:10] qubits

What I was trying to do was to export the noise model using `NoiseModel.to_dict()`, modifying that dictionary properly and then using the `NoiseModel.from_dict()` function. The problem is that `from_dict()` function is deprecated. I don't have any ideas on how to circumvent the problem.